# dlopen(3) always returns null when trying to get a dynamic library's handle in C# on Ubuntu using Mono

Tags: c#, ubuntu, null, mono, dlopen

I am a bit at a loss at this point as I have read every other relevant post to this issue, but none of them helped me resolve my problem.

I am trying to get a native Linux C++ .so library's handle in my C# code. I am using LoadLibrary and a native Windows C++ .dll when running on a Windows environment, which works great.

On the Linux side, though, dlopen does not work it seems. See the example below.

```
   // Flags for dlopen 
    private const int RTLD_NOW = 2;
    private const int RTLD_GLOBAL = 8;
    [DllImport("libdl.so")]
    static extern IntPtr dlopen(string filename, int flags);

    [DllImport("libdl.so")]
    static extern IntPtr dlsym(IntPtr handle, string symbol);

    [DllImport("libdl.so")]
    static extern int dlclose(IntPtr hModule);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public delegate IntPtr NativeFunctionExample();

    private static IntPtr libHandle;
    public bool LoadFoo()
    {
        // This always returns a null pointer, despite libfoo.so being in executable directory
        libHandle = dlopen("./libfoo.so", RTLD_GLOBAL | RTLD_NOW);
        if (libHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            return false;

        IntPtr fAddr = dlsym(libHandle, "NativeFunctionExample");
        NativeFunctionExample nativeFunction = (NativeFunctionExample)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(fAddr, typeof(NativeFunctionExample));
        nativeFunction();

        return dlclose(libHandle) == 0;
    }
```

Cannot get dlopen to return anything except a null pointer. Both the executable and the library are 32 bit. The library is always copied on execution to the working directory.

When running the program with:

```
    sudo MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug" MONO_LOG_MASK="dll" mono foo.exe
```

I get this output:

```
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libdl.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/share/foo/bin/x86/Debug/libdl.so': '/usr/share/foo/bin/x86/Debug/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/share/foo/bin/x86/Debug/libdl.so': '/usr/share/foo/bin/x86/Debug/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/libdl.so': '/usr/lib/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/libdl.so': '/usr/lib/libdl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library 'libdl.so'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: 'libdl.so' ('libdl.so').
Mono: Searching for 'dlopen'.
Mono: Probing 'dlopen'.
Mono: Found as 'dlopen'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
Mono: DllImport loaded library '(null)'.
Mono: DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
Mono: Searching for 'LoadLibrary'.
Mono: Probing 'LoadLibrary'.
Mono: Could not find 'LoadLibrary' due to 'mono: undefined symbol: LoadLibrary'.
Mono: Probing 'LoadLibrary'.
Mono: Could not find 'LoadLibrary' due to 'mono: undefined symbol: LoadLibrary'.
Mono: Probing 'LoadLibraryA'.
Mono: Could not find 'LoadLibraryA' due to 'mono: undefined symbol: LoadLibraryA'.
Mono: Probing 'LoadLibraryA'.
Mono: Could not find 'LoadLibraryA' due to 'mono: undefined symbol: LoadLibraryA'.
```

And the program ends after that (I kill it if no library handle was obtained).

Would really appreciate some insight as to why this may be happening.

This is being ran in Ubuntu 16.04.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Off: You seem to be mixing platforms and languages. On Windows platform, you could use C-language and LoadLibrary+GetProcAddress; on Linux platform, it is C-language, dlopen+dlsym.

Comment: That is indeed what I am doing. I use LoadLibrary + GetProcAddress on Windows, and it works great. In the above code I am attempting to replicate it on an Ubuntu environment and I get the described behavior. Sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: I am experiencing a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765486/dlsym-returns-null-where-getprocaddress-returns-valid-intptr), perhaps my code can help you get past `dlopen` returning `NULL`.